# How to display only one of the show/hide buttons using jquery?

Tags: jquery

I am stuck here.  Here is what I am trying to do..If the image and description list are visible, only the hide button should be displayed. If the image and description list are hidden, only the show button should be visible.  Here is what I tried to do:

```
$("#hide").toggle('slow');
$("#show").toggle('slow');
```

Here is my js code:  $(document).ready(function(){ $("#hide").click(function(){ $("img, dl").hide(); }); $("#show").click(function(){ $("img, dl").show(); $(document).ready(function(){ $('#show').hide(); function clickHandler() { $('#hide').toggle('slow'); $('#show').toggle('slow'); } }); }); }); When the page loads only the hide button should show. If the image and description lists are not visible, the show button should be displayed. Both buttons are displayed when the page loads
What is wrong with this?

Comment: `.toggle` is deprecated.  It was removed from jQuery in the version prior to the current one.

Comment: @RobertHarvey You're talking about http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/ and OP is using http://api.jquery.com/toggle/ which has not been deprecated.

Comment: @user2958278 There is nothing *really* wrong with those two lines of code. We need to see more of your JS. And please tell us what is actually happening when you click on the buttons?

Comment: Here is my javascript code: <script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#hide").click(function(){
   $("img, dl").hide();
  });
  
  
  
  $("#show").click(function(){
  $("img, dl").show();

 });
  });

Answer (score 0):

We need to see more of your code to find potential errors - there is nothing wrong with those two lines. And we need to know what is the problem you're facing.

Anyway, here's a possible solution. `.toggle()` toggles visibility so if only one button should be visible then you need to hide one of them first. This can be done with CSS or with jQuery.

Assuming that this is your markup:

```
<button id="show">Show</button>
<button id="hide">Hide</button>
```

If by default everything is visible, the Show button should be hidden:

```
<button id="show" style="display:none;">Show</button>
<button id="hide">Hide</button>
```

Or you can use a special class. For example `.hidden {display:none;}`

Otherwise, you can hide the button on page load:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#show').hide();
});
```

Then you can use `.toggle()` in the click event handler:

```
function clickHandler() {
    $('#hide').toggle('slow');
    $('#show').toggle('slow');
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#show').hide();

    $('#hide, #show').on('click', clickHandler);
});
```

Here is an example: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jfrej/VKnHv/)

Comment: Here is my js code: <script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#hide").click(function(){
   $("img, dl").hide();
  });
  
  
  
  $("#show").click(function(){
  $("img, dl").show();

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#show').hide();
 
 function clickHandler() {
    $('#hide').toggle('slow');
    $('#show').toggle('slow');
}
});
 });
  });  When the page loads only the hide button should show.  If the image and description lists are not visible, the show button should be displayed.  Both buttons are displayed when the page loads.

Answer (score 0):

### Please include JQuery Library in your project to run this code

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 
 if($("#mode").val() == 'N') {
  $("#req_button").html("<input type='submit' value='Save Record' id='btnSave'>").show();
 }
 
 $("#mode").change(function(){
  var mode = $("#mode").val();
  if(mode == 'N') {
   $("#req_button").html("<input type='submit' value='Save Record' id='btnSave'>").show();
  } else if(mode == 'M') {
   $("#req_button").html("<input type='submit' value='Update Record' id='btnUpdate'>").show();
  } else if(mode == 'R') {
   $("#req_button").html("<input type='submit' value='Remove Record' id='btnRemove'>").show();
  }
 });
 
});
```

```html
<td>
  <select name="mode" id="mode">
    <option value="N">New</option>
    <option value="M">Modify</option>
    <option value="R">Remove</option>
  </select>
</td>

<td><span id="req_button"></span></td>
```